# What DirectShow uses for data transfer between filters?

Tags: filter, directshow, transfer

What does DirectShow use for data transfer between filters? (pipes or what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectShow handles data chunks in "media samples", which are simply buffers, implemented through the `IMediaSample` COM interface. To allocate samples is used a COM-based memory manager, the `IMemAllocator` interface, that should be implement by filters. To transfer samples is used the method `IMemAllocator::GetBuffer`.

Fully documented there: [Data Flow in the Filter Graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388376)

Comment: To transfer samples, the sender calls the IMemInputPin::Receive method.